# How to use javascript-created element as jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to create an html button with id "cancel".  On my actual page, clicking my #edit button will successfully create my cancel button.  However I am unable to then use this cancel button for future jQuery actions.  Is there a solution to this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#edit").click(function() {
    $("#button").html("<input id='cancel' type='button' value='cancel' />");
  });
  
  // Here I want to access my new button
  
  $("#cancel").click(function() {
    ('p').hide();  
  });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='button'><input id='edit' type='button' value=edit /></span>
<p>Hide me upon cancel</p>
```

Comment: Yes, it's called [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

You are also missing jquery selector while targeting p elements.

```
 $("#button").on('click','#cancel',function() {
   $('p').hide();  
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.  And for catching the typo :)

Comment: @Tortooga: glad it helps

Comment: As a bit of a follow up question... what if I want clicking "cancel" to cause the button to revert back to a functioning "edit" button?  I tried to store the contents of the original #button as a variable, and then reassign #button after clicking cancel.  But this puts me back at my original issue where the button cannot be selected by jQuery.

Comment: for that you will need to delegate `#edit` event. exactly the same way done for cancel button